# Блокировка нажатий клавиш на клавиатуре

Tags: java, winapi, swing, gui, awt

Как с помощью средств awt и swing или иных средств java сделать так чтобы при нажатии всех клавиш на клавиатуре кроме букв и цифр, ничего не происходило, чтобы нажатие блокировалось?

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;
public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e){
    System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}
public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key Typed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    }
}
```

Comment: e.getKeyCode() e - ето код клавиши?

Comment: import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener; среда не определаеть ети библиотеки

Comment: @user221117 эти библиотеки нужно скачивать и устанавливать дополнительно к основным

Comment: все разобралься, но всеравно но не во время нажатия на клавишу действия происходить то что должно бить при нажатие на клавишу но оно не блокирует нажатие